# Mercurial and Bitbucked: how to update fork?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I'm new to mercurial and examining bitbucket.org infrastructure. If i fork some project at bitbucked via "fork" button - what is the preferred way to keep fork up-to-date? Is fork "origin" saved somewhere in forked repository? Of course i can manually specify repository in "pull" command - but this seems awkward to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the bitbucket interface there is a notion of "origin", but I don't think you can do a pull within bitbucket.

Within your local clone of your fork you can name URLs in your `.hg/hgrc` file's `[paths]` section, after which you can just do 'hg pull NAME`.  For example I'll often do:

```
[paths]
upstream = http://path/to/repo/from/which/I/forked
```

Then you can do `hg pull upstream` to pull in those changes.  For more options see `hg help paths` and http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths